# Concatenate javascript "strings" into objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a method which should concatenate two strings(that are result of json stringify) into one string(which should look like json object with it's structure).

First one :

```
{"text":"klk","makeId":"9"}
```

Second one:

```
{"firstname":"jjk","lastname":"jkjk","email":"jjkjk@sdasd.com"}
```

How do I concatenate these two into one json string i.e :

```
{"text":"klk","makeId":"9", "firstname":"jjk","lastname":"jkjk","email":"jjkjk@sdasd.com"}
```

I could strip `{"` and `"}` then split by comma and achieve this result. I'm wondering is there better more smart way to do this?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation. Parse the JSON, consolidate the objects' content, and serialize the result.

Comment: @hall.stephenk no issues, it's just ugly code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These strings are JSON! Parse them, merge them like objects and stringify them again.

---

```
var data1 = JSON.parse(json1);
var data2 = JSON.parse(json2);
var data = merge(data1, data2); // implement merge!
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

`JSON` should be available in all recent browsers.

```
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    var hasOwn = {}.hasOwnProperty;
    for (var key in obj2) {
        if (hasOwn.call(obj2, key)) {
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}
```

Comment: I agree, but I cannot give you a +1 because "implement merge" is a pretty big step if the OP is not a JavaScript expert.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Not really. I'm by no means a JavaScript expert (with that I mean, I've written Hello World and that's basically it) and I could do it in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @Cubic If you know about `hasOwnProperty`, and finding an guaranteed unmodified version of it, then you are definitely closer to expert than novice :-)